# How should we address a person from Israel such as a Christian or other non-Jewish individual?

Tags: israel, jews

Is the word Jew a derogatory word?

I assumed that Jews originated from the kingdom of Judah, but there were two kingdoms; Israel and Judah.

Comment: How is this a question on Christianity?

Comment: [Related (and closed) question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32390/where-did-the-term-jew-come-from).

Comment: The same way a Christian might address a person from any other ethnic or religious background, by "Sir" or "Madam" or "friend".

Answer (score 2):

**How should we address a person from Israel such as a Christian or other non-Jewish individual?**

The modern definition of a person or citizen from the State of Israel is known as an ***Israeli***.

> Citizens of the **State of Israel** are called Israelis, a term carrying no ethnological or religious connotations. - [**Jew** (Encyclopaedia Britannica)](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Jew-people)

Historically speaking a Jew was considered any person belonging to the worldwide group that constitutes, through descent or conversion, a continuation of the ancient Jewish people, who were themselves descendants of the Hebrews of the Bible (Old Testament).

Being a Jew is not considered by most individuals to be a derogatory term. Like any other ethnic communities, they deserve to be treated with respect and dignity.

> **Jew**, Hebrew Yĕhūdhī or Yehudi, any person whose religion is Judaism. In the broader sense of the term, **a Jew is any person belonging to the worldwide group that constitutes, through descent or conversion, a continuation of the ancient Jewish people, who were themselves descendants of the Hebrews of the Bible (Old Testament)**. In ancient times, a Yĕhūdhī was originally a member of Judah—i.e., either of the tribe of Judah (one of the 12 tribes that took possession of the Promised Land) or of the subsequent Kingdom of Judah (in contrast to the rival Kingdom of Israel to the north). The Jewish people as a whole, initially called Hebrews (ʿIvrim), were known as Israelites (Yisreʾelim) from the time of their entrance into the Holy Land to the end of the Babylonian Exile (538 BCE). Thereafter, the term Yĕhūdhī (Latin: Judaeus; French: Juif; German: Jude; and English: Jew) was used to signify all adherents of Judaism, because the survivors of the Exile (former inhabitants of the Kingdom of Judah) were the only Israelites who had retained their distinctive identity. (The 10 tribes of the northern kingdom of Israel had been dispersed after the Assyrian conquest of 721 BCE and were gradually assimilated by other peoples.) The term Jew is thus derived through the Latin Judaeus and the Greek Ioudaios from the Hebrew Yĕhūdhī. The latter term is an adjective occurring only in the later parts of the Hebrew Bible and signifying a descendant of Yehudhah (Judah), the fourth son of Jacob, whose tribe, together with that of his half brother Benjamin, constituted the Kingdom of Judah. - [**Jew** (Encyclopaedia Britannica)](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Jew-people)

Comment: "Being a Jew is not considered by most individuals to be a derogatory term" It definitely can be used that way, though, especially when it's used as a verb to mean "scamming or stealing money". Of course, using it that way would be against the rules of this site.

Comment: Very comprehensive reply. Thank you!